# organizing all the words in a text file in an array or linked list using python

Tags: python, arrays, file, split, linked-list

I have a text file of the following format.

```
<InitialNode>-><MergeNode *merge>->("Prepare for election")
->["Equipment, voter lists, ballot styles and/or ballots"]-><ForkNode>
{ ->("Prepare for voting (precinct)")-><ForkNode>
{ ->("Gather in-person vote") // Includes early voting.
->["Ballots and/or ballot images"]->(Collect *c),
"Precinct count"->("Count (precinct count)")
->["Machine totals"]->0..1(*c)
}
```

I need to split the text file and store the elements in such a way that

```
array[0]=<InitialNode>
array[1]=->
array[2]=<MergeNode *merge>
array[3]=->
array[4]=("Prepare for election")
array[5]=-> 
array[6]=["Equipment, voter lists, ballot styles and/or ballots"]
array[7]=->
```

and so on.

In short I need to split the entire text on the basis of ->.

All the things that comes between '->' , ',' , '}' , '}'  must be stored in a linked list or 
array.

How could I do this using python?

Comment: This is one weird format there. Can you generalise the grammar a bit? Also, can the separator occur inside a value?

Answer (score 0):

If your initial string is stored in x.

To get all the text in x,do

```
x = open("/tmp/filename").read()
```

This should do the trick

```
import re
splitter = re.compile('->')
array = splitter.split(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the built-in `split` method of strings.

```
>>> with open('txtfile.txt', 'r') as f:
...     txt = f.read()
... 
>>> txt.split('->')
['\n<InitialNode>', '<MergeNode *merge>', '("Prepare for election")\n', 
 '["Equipment, voter lists, ballot styles and/or ballots"]', '<ForkNode>\n{ ', 
 '("Prepare for voting (precinct)")', '<ForkNode>\n{ ', 
 '("Gather in-person vote") // Includes early voting.\n', 
 '["Ballots and/or ballot images"]', '(Collect *c),\n"Precinct count"', 
 '("Count (precinct count)")\n', '["Machine totals"]', '0..1(*c)\n}\n'
]
```

But I'm not sure what you mean by "All the things that comes between '->' , ',' , '}' , '}' must be stored in a linked list or array." Does this do that? Or do you need to split up these substrings further?

Comment: @rekharajct, I'm also assuming that you don't actually need the `'->'` strings between each item; if you do, let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: I have tried the code above.What I have given is the specification of an activity diagram.What I intend is to convert the specification to xml format.Every element in the specification has a meaning.For example -> indicates connection, comma indicates branching and so on.So I need to store each and every element- , ,},-> and so on in a list,traverse it  and generate the xml.

Comment: @rekharajct, sounds like you need a bonafide tokenizer. I'll give it some thought...

Comment: What I have given is the specification of an activity diagram.I need to parse the file and create an xml equivalent for the specification.Every element in the specification has a meaning. For example -> indicates connection, comma indicates branching and so on.What I intend is to store every element in the specification in a list including commas,braces,semi colon,arrows and then traverse the list and generate the equivalent xml for each element.